# SQL to Mimic Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an finance issue that we are trying to put into a SQLServer 2005 database (default installation). We are doing quarterly comparison from this year to the same quarter last year i.e. **(2013Q1 - 2012Q1) / 20132Q1**. Can someone write a query to return an ordered list from 1 - 9 with the quarter over quarter as described above?

```
In data set
QUART   REV
2011Q1  6,175,352 
2011Q2  6,591,067 
2011Q3  6,219,978 
2011Q4  6,189,939 
2012Q1  7,178,652 
2012Q2  6,731,467 
2012Q3  6,949,978 
2012Q4  6,679,939 
2013Q1  6,242,802 
2013Q2  6,421,902 
2013Q3  6,667,007 
2013Q4  6,575,004
```

```
Expected output
QUART   COMP
1   0.1625
2   0.0213
3   0.1174
4   0.0792
5   -0.1304
6   -0.0460
7   -0.0407
8   -0.0157
```

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Firstly...you really could have saved yourself so much trouble by splitting your "QUART" column into `Year` and `Quarter`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the above comment, it is much easier if you split quart:

`create table t 
(   yr int not null
,   qt int not null
,   salary int not null 
,       primary key (yr,qt) )`

`insert into t (yr,qt,salary)
values  (2011,1,6175352) 
    ,   (2011,2,6591067) 
    ,   (2011,3,6219978) 
    ,   (2011,4,6189939) 
    ,   (2012,1,7178652) 
    ,   (2012,2,6731467) 
    ,   (2012,3,6949978) 
    ,   (2012,4,6679939) 
    ,   (2013,1,6242802) 
    ,   (2013,2,6421902) 
    ,   (2013,3,6667007) 
    ,   (2013,4,6575004)`

`select row_number() over (order by yr, qt) as quart, comp 
 from (
    select t1.yr, t1.qt
         , (1.0*t1.salary - (select salary 
                             from t t2 
                             where t2.yr = t1.yr - 1 
                               and t2.qt = t1.qt)
            ) / t1.salary comp 
    from t t1 
    where t1.yr >= 2012
)`

my numbers deviates from yours, I have not investigate why but it should give you a start.

Comment: Your solution really helped me see things through! Due to other considerations not on the original posting, I opted to LEFT JOIN two datasets; one for the year, the other for the year before.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of formatting in a SQL query, but the exercise was fun.  Normally, you should elevate formatting (such as rounding) to the application level, but since you're trying to emulate Excel...

```
/*sample data*/
DECLARE @T TABLE ( Quart CHAR(6), Rev INT )

INSERT  INTO @T
        ( Quart, Rev )
VALUES  ( '2011Q1', 6175352 ),
        ( '2011Q2', 6591067 ),
        ( '2011Q3', 6219978 ),
        ( '2011Q4', 6189939 ),
        ( '2012Q1', 7178652 ),
        ( '2012Q2', 6731467 ),
        ( '2012Q3', 6949978 ),
        ( '2012Q4', 6679939 ),
        ( '2013Q1', 6242802 ),
        ( '2013Q2', 6421902 ),
        ( '2013Q3', 6667007 ),
        ( '2013Q4', 6575004 );


/*query begins here 
    cte is used to parse quart column into years & quarters */

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   Yr = CONVERT(SMALLINT, LEFT(Quart, 4))
                      , Qt = RIGHT(Quart, 1)
                      , Rev
               FROM     @T
             )
/*join cte to itself to compare last year same quarter
    ROW_NUMBER used to get sequential ordering
    CONVERT to numeric and rounding to get formatting
*/
    SELECT  QUART = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.Yr
          , b.Qt) , 
          COMP = CONVERT(NUMERIC(5,4), ROUND((a.Rev-b.Rev*1.0)/ b.Rev, 4))
    FROM    cte a
            JOIN cte b ON b.Qt = a.Qt
                          AND b.Yr = a.Yr - 1
```